# Get ID of Last Inserted Record - Access DAO, ODBC, SQL Server 2008 Identity Field

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, odbc

It's a very common question but I'm having trouble getting the ID of the last inserted record. I'm using DAO with ODBC linked tables to duplicate a record and it's child records. My tables are in SQL Server 2008 and have Identity fields for ID fields.

Here's what I've tried so far. My first bit of code here results in error 3167, Record is Deleted. If I do a debug.Print the recordset actually contains 3 records.

```
Dim r as DAO.Recordset, db as DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set r = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM item ORDER BY DateTimeModified DESC", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
r.AddNew
'Set field values here
r.Update 'Completes without error
r.Bookmark = r.LastModified
Debug.Print r("ItemID") 'Error 3167, Record is deleted
```

Here's the next thing I tried:

```
Debug.Print db.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@identity FROM item")(0)
```

This last one completes without any problem but the value returned is incorrect. Where the actual new ItemID is 321 this returns the value 614. The value it is returning does appear to be incremental (it changes as I keep testing this) but it does not appear to relate at all to my table. There is no field with the value 614. I've double checked to make sure I'm looking up the correct table.

I know I could use something like DLookup or DMax but I don't think that would be considered bullet proof in a multi-user environment.

I suppose I could use a Stored Procedure with ADO to get around this problem. I'm wondering if that is my only option?

**Edit1:**
I'm now using the following code and it is doing what I need/want it to. I suspect this is basically the same as using DMax.

```
Dim r as DAO.Recordset, db as DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set r = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM item ORDER BY ItemID DESC", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
r.AddNew
'Set field values here
r.Update
r.Requery
r.MoveFirst
Debug.Print r("ItemID")
```

Comment: Can you use a passthrough query or stored procedure? I am pretty sure you should not be using @@identity with SQL Server (http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/6_Different_Ways_To_Get_The_Current_Identity_Value).

Comment: I think its `SELECT TOP 2 ... Order by DateTimeModified` that's messing you up. Also `Select @@Identity` isn't intended to bue used with a from clause and isn't likely doing what you think it is. Also if you don't want to use an SP you might try executing an Insert and select in one batch. e.g. `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... ; SELECT * FROM items where ItemID = Scope_Identity()`

Comment: @ConradFrix I've tried different SELECT statements in for the Recordset 'r' and it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I was using this information to guide me but I guess maybe it's not accurate: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/3507c845-66a6-4e13-8876-f6e5faae8dba

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm aware `@@IDENTITY` doesn't work for cursor-based inserts. DAO and ADO both use cursors behind the scenes.

After you `.Update` the record you should be able to get the identity value back simply by reading the value.

The following works fine for me via an ADO Recordset opened with Keyset semantics:

```
r.Update
Debug.Print r("ItemID")
```

The following works fine for me via a DAO Recordset opened with Dynaset semantics:

```
r.Update
r.Bookmark = r.LastModified
Debug.Print r("ItemID")
```

You should avoid `.Requery` and `.MoveFirst`, you're introducing concurrency problems. Consider:

```
Dim r as DAO.Recordset, db as DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set r = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM item ORDER BY ItemID DESC", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
r.AddNew
''// Set field values here
r.Update
''// At this point another user adds a new record
r.Requery
r.MoveFirst ''// ORDER BY ItemID DESC means that you're going to see the new user's row
Debug.Print r("ItemID")
```

Comment: I was trying to find a DAO-based solution.

Comment: @HK1 I've updated my answer to point out a problem with your current implementation.

Comment: No, your solution doesn't work in DAO. And yes, you are right that theoretically another user could add a new record in between the update and requery. That's the problem with using DMax as well.

Comment: For DAO you've posted the same code I have that produces error 3167. I suspect you didn't recreate the entire environment using SQL Server 2008 with an identity field and ODBC Linked Tables.

Comment: @HK1 I did not. What type is the identity field, and what is the primary key of the table? While we're at it, does Access see the primary key? I.e., you added the linked table after the primary key was created.

Comment: The identity field is int. It's named ItemID in this case and it is the primary key for the table. And yes, Access does see it as the primary key.

Comment: @HK1 I have recreated the scenario and it seems to work for me. I chose the SQL Server 2000 driver instead of SQL Server Native Client, although I doubt using an older driver would make a difference. Perhaps refresh the linked table to make sure Access sees the available keys and indexes?

Comment: My table link is deleted and recreated every time the database is opened.

Comment: My 2c: we have a form whose record source is an SQL 2008 linked table with an int column `Id` configured as identity. Were able to simply query `Me!Id` in form's `AfterInsert` event handler to make further use of it in VBA (e.g. refresh product lists).

Comment: this worked for me (Access, DAO, C#, during a transaction) :

`recordset.Update();
recordset.MoveLast();
int test = recordset.Fields["ID"].Value;`

Answer (score 1):

The following works as expected (using Office 2013 and SQL Server 2014)

```
Set rsProjects = db.OpenRecordset("JobProjects", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges Or dbAppendOnly)
rsProjects.AddNew
rsProjects.Name = 'xyz'
rsProjects.Update
rsProjects.Bookmark = rsProjects.LastModified
lNewProjectID = rsProjects!ProjectID.Value
```

Key point: instead of using 'SELECT TOP 2' or 'SELECT TOP 1', etc. I used 'dbSeeChanges **Or dbAppendOnly**'. I verified in sql profiler that opening the recordset does not generate any queries to SQL Server.

When you issue the update, access generates an insert statement followed immediately by a SELECT @@IDENTITY to get the id of the new record.

Edited: add missing .AddNew, Remove duplicate .Update.

Comment: using update twice, does not that give error, update without add/edit etc.

Comment: @ShamYemul yes that was a mistake in my code, I missed the .AddNew and have an extra .Update, will fix my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

it dosnt work with sql server backend(in multi user app
). for access table it work
for sql use stored procedure.use this way

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddAsset

  @Name VARCHAR(500),
  @URL  VARCHAR(2000),
  @new_identity INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT dbo.Assets(Name, URL) SELECT @Name, @URL;
SET @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END 
GO
```

then use this sp in front end

Answer (score -1):

Simply get the value of the key field before you execute the `Update` statement.  As pointed out in the comment below, this process will not work if you are using a different backend than Microsoft Access.  But I leave this response here in case that is your use case and you are just searching for an answer to the general question of how you get the ID of the last inserted record.

For your example, you can do this with Microsoft Access:

```
Dim r as DAO.Recordset, db as DAO.Database
Dim lKey As Long
Set db = CurrentDb
Set r = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 2 * FROM item ORDER BY DateTimeModified DESC", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
r.AddNew
    'Set field values here
    'Retrieve the key value before executing the Update
    lKey = r!ItemID
r.Update
Debug.Print lKey
```

Comment: The above will not work for SQL server - but only for JET/ACE tables. SQL server does not generate nor return the autonumber PK value until such time the record is saved. You have to FIRST execute a update, and then best to use bookmark property to move the record pointer back to "lastmodified" since the update WHEN adding (and ONLY when adding) causes the recordpointer to move off the current record you just "updated". The lastmodifed bookmark is not required for updating of existing reocrds, but is for new records.